# Double tables select show?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem...I have 2 tables, Table1 and Table2.

```
Table1:
id,int(11)
text,varchar(11)

Table2:
id,int(11)
agentid,int(11)  
unique(id,agentid)
```

Table2 has many id and agent ids in it.  The data for the id in table 2 came from table 1.

I have an agentid say $aid.  This has many id's associated with it in table 2.

I am trying to get the set of text values out from table 1 associated with all ids which are related to agentid $aid from table 2.

Does that make sense?!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select text from table1 where id in
(
select id from table2 where agentid = <your aid>
)
```

This will give you all text rows for given agentid.
The same can be done using join too -

```
select t1.text from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.agentid = <your aid>
```

Comment: Is one method particularly preferred to the other here?  Like is the top one faster or better for small tables etc?

Comment: @David19801 - I think the join is preferred over the other one depending on how many records you have in your table. More records, the join performs better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where agentid = $aid
```

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
$sql = "select t1.text from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.agentid = {$aid}";
```

Try not to include the $aid directly in the query, but escape it and/or use prepared statements with query parameters.